# Native base icon button on top

Tags: javascript, react-native, native-base

[image]

Native base is really a great library for styling react / react-native. I only have one question for icon button, I wish the icon on top and text in the bottom, not align together. I have tried to `alignSelf:'center'` for the icon and text but it doesn't work. Anyone can help ? Thanks a lot.

```
<Button transparent style={styles.capturebtn}>
    <Icon name="camera" type="MaterialCommunityIcons" style={styles.capturebtnicon}/>
    <Text style={styles.capturebtntxt} uppercase={false}>Open Camera</Text>
</Button>   

  capturebtntxt:{
    alignSelf:'center',
    fontSize:15,
    fontFamily:'Gotham-Medium',
    color:'#AAAAAA'
  },
  capturebtnicon:{
    alignSelf:'center',
    color:'#E3E3E3',
    fontSize:35
  },
  capturebtn:{
    elevation:0,
    borderColor:'#e5e5e5',
    borderWidth:1,
    borderRadius:7,
    justifyContent:'center',
    alignItems:'center',
    width:((Dimensions.get('window').width - 150 - 60) / 2) - 10
  },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found `flexDirection: 'column'` for button fixed this. =)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use `vertical`

> vertical - true - boolean -  Use this prop to vertically align footer elements
>   like icons and text

example

[image]